# RegEx C# get substring of 12 characters which contains at least one digit AND letter

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
String testString = "Some text F4LE8AWMF87E and again some text";
Match myMatch = Regex.Match(testString, "\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{12,}\b");
myLabel.Text = testString.Substring(myMatch.Index, myMatch.Length);
```

myLabel should now show "F4LE8AWMF87E" but it doesn't.

What is wrong?

Comment: F4LE8AWMF87 is only 11 characters.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I just changed it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's much easier to achieve with good old loops. Just split the string by the word boundary `\b`, than iterate over fragments counting the number of occurences of letters and digits.

Comment: Either you didn't understand me or I didn't understand you. I have to get a part of a string.

Comment: I strongly agree with the regex approach. On Rubular yours works => http://rubular.com/r/Rj38c06FQC

Comment: I did not know this site. Thank you. Makes it much easier to check RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the char '\' in a string literal.

```
String testString = "Some text F4LE8AWMF87E and again some text";
Match myMatch = Regex.Match(testString, @"\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{12,}\b");
myLabel.Text = myMatch.Value;
```

Comment: Gives empty string, so it just don't work. Have you tried launching it?

Comment: @SoBiT Sorry, Edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following please:

Reference at [Rublar](http://rubular.com/r/UTO765DZ2w) although C# escape makes the slight difference. You can test it out. I believe you if you had to_upper case within the regex, that would make it better :)

```
String testString = "Some text F4LE8AWMF87 and again some text";
    Match myMatch = 
    Regex.Match(testString, "\b[a-zA-Z\d]{11,12}\b");
    myLabel.Text = testString.Substring(myMatch.Index, myMatch.Length);
```

Comment: There is already the answer, and you only had to escape forward slash in C# by @ :D interesting.